Rails 7 action cable deploy in Heroku doesn't work
I need to update the show page with the new items created, so I'm using web socket which works perfectly in local server but in production is not executing the reload page in the stimulus controller. Also in the console of the web inspector I got the error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).   https://fillo.herokuapp.com/assets/controllers

---- channel ----
station_channel.rb
class StationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "station_#{params[:room]}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
  end
end

---- controller ----
 app/javascript/controllers - stations_controller.js:
class StationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "station_#{params[:room]}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
  end
end

---- production.rb -----
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
  config.action_cable.url = "wss://fillo.herokuapp.com/cable"
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ "https://fillo.herokuapp.com", /https:\/\/fillo.herokuapp.com.*/]

---- application.js -----
app/javascript/
import "./controllers"

---- cable.yml ----
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV['REDIS_URL'] %>
  channel_prefix: bar_menu_production

---- importmap.rb ----
pin "application", to: "application.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin "@rails/actioncable", to: "@rails--actioncable.js" # @7.1.3

---- controller.rb ----
deliveries_controller.rb
  def order_subitem_create
    subitems = params.require(:body).require(:subitems)
    subitems.each do |subitem|
      order_subitem = OrderItem.new
      order_subitem.subitem_id = subitem
      order_subitem.order_id = @order.id
      break unless order_subitem.save!
    end
    action_cable
  end

  def action_cable
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "station_#{@order.station_id}",
      {
        action: "created"
      }
    )
    Rails.logger.info("Broadcasting to station_#{@order.station_id} with action: created")
  end

console:
2024-07-14T11:47:30.550971+00:00 app[web.1]: [070ee631-f469-41fe-b775-5cf43ba9d316] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/controllers"):
2024-07-14T11:47:30.550972+00:00 app[web.1]: [070ee631-f469-41fe-b775-5cf43ba9d316]

Can someone recognise why do I have this error:
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/controllers"
when I'm sending a post request to create a new item the console shows that the action cable in the controller is executing:
2024-07-14T11:49:22.515631+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2024-07-14T11:49:22.515574 #2]  INFO -- : [013d79c6-af44-43fd-af79-2a72e88794fc] Broadcasting to station_3 with action: created

I am having a similar issue. Make any progress in this?
